# Create JSON to send API request in R

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

This might have been asked and solved before, I just can't get a straightforward answer.

I got the following:

```
text <- 'Testing to be translated'
```

Which I am trying to get into JSON format like:

```
[{"Text": "Testing to be translated"}]
```

I have tried using toJSON but I could not get that structure.
Additionally, I did some quick-fix:

```
paste0('[{"Text":"', text, '"}]')
```

Which would work fine; however, I have some strings with the " and ' characters in it and they would break this code.

Any input would be helpful.
More context: I am using a GET request to translate text from Azure server, could not use translateR so I am creating my own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array, pass `jsonlite::toJSON` an unnamed list or vector. You should also set `auto_unbox=TRUE` so that scalars aren't treated as arrays.

```
text <- 'Testing to be translated'
jsonlite::toJSON(list(list(Text=text)), auto_unbox=TRUE)

# [{"Text":"Testing to be translated"}]
```